# Install Microsoft Exchange in a machine running windows 7 x64?

Tags: exchange-server, windows-7-x64, mail-server

Can I and if not what is the best mail server can do that with machine running windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can't install Exchange onto the Windows 7 PC itself, your could run a Virtual PC off it with the appropriate server O/S running.

If you want an alternative mail server, try [VPOP3](http://www.pscs.co.uk/products/vpop3/index.php).  In order to use IMAP clients from it you would require the Professional version.

Comment: i'm asked about free windows mail servers i tried hmailserver before i want another one if available